# Sitemap for Google?

Tags: sitemaps

I need a Sitemap to comply with Google´s requirements for SEO...

I did the following:

1. Set System->Configuration->Google Sitemap->Generation Settings->Enabled to “Yes”
2. Created a Google Sitemap in Catalog->Google Sitemap
3. Create sitemap folder under public html
4. chmod the folder to 777

What suppose to happen now? Does the Sitemap appear somewhere on the site? Or does it not need to be visible on the front end? I am using the Access shop Lite theme (http://accessshopthemes.com/)

Comment: Make sure you have a cron job entry functioning that calls Magento's cron.php and that Magento's cron jobs are running. This is necessary for Magento to run the timed job that creates the sitemap every night.

Answer (score 1):

The sitemaps folder is needed before you create your sitemap in it. After that, Google Webmaster Tools is your friend. Go on there, upload your sitemap. It is all self explanatory from there.

You will need to check your sitemap over time, to check that it is being updated on cron and no 404s are being found by the google.

Answer (score 1):

the generic name for a sitemap is sitemap.xml in the root folder so a search engine can find it at yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml, your xml sitemap should naturally be here if configured correctly.  What you'll need to do is put it in your robots.txt file.  Write a line that tells search engines where it is located - "sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml" for google (or bing for that matter) you can submit your sitemap every time you change it within Google's search console (what was "Google Webmaster Tools") and the Bing equivalent whatever that's called, it it's in the robot.txt file all the other smaller  engines will pick up on it. :-)